# Magento 2: Product page popup on image click

Tags: magento2

Is there any possbilty for the product page pop up on click on image in Magento 2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use quick view extension. It will open product page in popup when you click quick view icon from category page.

Example extension: 
https://www.weltpixel.com/advance-product-quick-view.html

Comment: Thanks but i want quick view for only product page

Comment: Porduct page already contains product detail.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try [Quick View extension by Mageplaza](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-quick-view/)
This extension has some highlight features that I think will interest you:

- Product quick view popup
- User-friendly Ajax Cart
- Flexible to customize products in a popup
- Easy to customize pop-up content & animation effects
- Embedded Quick View